# How to upsample a vector to a certain length in python

Tags: python

Given a vector, [1,2,3,4,5] for example, how to upsample the vector with linear interpolation to a certain length, such as 45 in python.

Answer (score 0):

If it is linear, there should be a constant increase or decrease between each new element. In your case it is one. So sample the difference between two elements, then add that to the last element however many times you want to.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
num_add = 45 -len(a)
b = a[1] - a[0]
for z in range(1,num_add):
    a.append(b + a[-1])
```

I think this should work, although you may have to play with the range.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I interpreted your list of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as simply an example. If you want a script that will actually interpolate the series you give it, try this:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


# Line equation - doesn't have to be linear
def lin_eq(x, m, b):

    return x*m + b

# Your actual data
std_y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

# Index of data
std_x = np.arange(1, len(std_y) + 1)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(lin_eq, std_x, std_y)

top = 45

# Index of projected data
proj_x = np.arange(1, top + 1)

# Interpolated data
proj_y = lin_eq(proj_x, *popt)

print proj_y

[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15.
  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.  28.  29.  30.
  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  39.  40.  41.  42.  43.  44.  45.]
```